# Matrix of correlations between the residuals in a SEM fitted by R systemfit function

Tags: r, regression, correlation, structural-equation-modeling

Assume we would fit this model with `systemfit()` from the [systemfit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/) R package.

$y = \beta_1 x + \gamma_1 z + u$

$z = \beta_2 w + \gamma_2 y + v$

Now I can get an estimate of $Cor(u,v)$.

I know that one cause of endogenity is that there is a significant correlation between $u$ and $v$. But does this mean that I should look at correlation matrix provided by the `systemfit()` output in order to conclude if there is evidence that this correlation might be the reason for the endogenity?

Further if I control for the endogenity and the correlation between $u$ and $v$ decreases does this mean that some omitted variable is now controlled for such that the remaining error is just the residual noise?